A journal has published an AI-generated article under my name. What to do?
The Global International Journal of Innovative Research  has published a fake research article under my name, complete with a DOI doi:10.59613/global.v1i3.42. The article appears to be entirely AI-generated.  I never had anything to do with the article: I never created the text, nor did I submit it for publication.  I assume the journal has created and published the article to lend credence to its title.
The article's publication is disparaging me by associating my name with the article's drivel, the journal publishing such nonsense, and the unethical practice of publishing AI-generated text without appropriate acknowledgements. It seems that the article is gathering attention.  I became aware of it, when a colleague fell for it and found it relevant to one of our department's initiatives. What can I do?

This is a journal that's also been known to falsely claim individuals are part of its editorial board and refuse to remove their names. Not sure what the solution actually is.

A "Global International Journal of X" does not inspire confidence.  I'm sorry this has happened :-(

The journal gives a contact address in San Fransisco, but the links to the editors web pages appear to be set up to translate to Indonesian, so it is not clear (shall we say) that this is a genuine journal.  I suspect you are right in your assessment of why the article is there.

I think if these things become more common, it is time to introduce a concept of an anti-publication list. You list papers that you know are in your name but you haven't written. I guess it's perhaps not yet necessary, but maybe it will be.

@DikranMarsupial: Well, one of the phrases "Global International Journal" and "of Innovative Research" is a huge red sail (rather than merely a red flag) and the other one sets the sail on fire. I'm still undecided regarding which phrase plays which part...

I wondered if it would be legal to gather the contact emails of the corresponding authors of all the papers that the journal has published and tell them that they have published a paper that you didn't write.  Unfortunately they are not given on the website or the papers AFAICS.

@JochenGlueck - I think the two are mutually assured destruction phrases, and assigning cause vs effect is not productive here. What a weird world we live in though. Should I be upset if nobody publishes a false paper under my name? Hmmmm...

@JonCuster: "Should I be upset if nobody publishes a false paper under my name?" This question seems to be related to the anti-publication list suggested by Captain Emacs: A longer anti-publication lists counts positively in your CV (just as a longer publication list does) because each item there means that somebody found you important enough to abuse your name for a scam publication.

@JochenGlueck - of course, if the "author" is too famous then nobody would believe they actually wrote the paper. Seems like there is a sweet spot in the (complete unknown)->(Nobel Prize winner) continuum. Although posthumous articles by AI (not Al) Einstein might be an option...

To me, the bigger question is if the paper is retracted, how do you keep it from appearing like your paper got retracted.  Personally, I'd try reporting your case informally to the good people at Retraction Watch (https://retractionwatch.com/meet-the-retraction-watch-staff/) to see if they can offer any advice

Is that your actual university listed as your affiliation? Then they are being defamed too.

The links currently go to a 404 error, which suggests that you may have won (at least for the specific case, rather than the general problem),

Although the links in the OP give a 404 Not Found, the page of the article still appears on google and the entire PDF of the article comes up on google.

@bolbteppa It takes time for Google to update. Three out of five of the top results when I search OP's name and the journal are about the article being fake. The other two are from the journal itself, but one was removed and the other updated to not have that fake paper or OP's name.

Do you think it's relevant that the article was AI-generated? Would it be better or worse if a human had written the nonsense? All that matters is that you didn't write it.

@barmar Good question! That the article was written by AI is a relevant fact, because many organizations consider it unethical to use AI without an appropriate acknowledgement.

@ScottSeidman Very important consideration!

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer and this isn't legal advice.
Given that this journal appears to be a complete scam and is likely to be unresponsive to your requests to remove the article, I think you may have no choice but to treat this as a legal matter involving defamation. You, and potentially your institution, may have a valid claim that the journal's attribution to you of things you didn't say hurts your reputation and that of your institution, and constitutes defamation.
As a first step, I would approach my university's legal counsel (or similar legal department - any large university has one) and ask for their advice and assistance in addressing this issue. As @Dawn said in a comment, they may be able to help by writing a letter to the journal on behalf of the university threatening to take legal action. Perhaps that will be enough to get the journal to take down the article.
If a letter doesn't help, the university may actually need to take concrete legal action against the journal (e.g., filing a lawsuit). If they are willing to do that, that's great for you. If they aren't, you may need to take matters into your own hands by hiring a lawyer.
Legal action doesn't sound like an easy or cheap route to solve the problem, but I'm not sure there is an easier way, so you'll have to decide whether it's worth it.
You can also consider posting a question on law.stackexchange.com to get additional advice on whether the journal's behavior can be considered defamation, and what are some available courses of action. They will very likely have ideas I haven't thought of.
Good luck!

Did the fake article list your affiliation as well as your name? If you're going to sue, you want to be able to show that they specifically meant you and not just someone with the same name.

@Ray apparently yes, per this comment: "My name isn't unique, but my name and the matching affiliation given in the article identify me uniquely and unambiguously."

+1. Neither am I a lawyer, but even if defamation is not applicable, I'd be confident that this kind of impersonation (and using your affiliation, so it definitely affects your institution) is illegal. The question is whether the relevant legal standards apply in the country where the journal is based.

I posted a question on Law SE asking whether this kind of behaviour would constitute defamation.

Update! As of 13 Sept. 2024, It looks like they took down the article.

You can contact the journal with your complaint. I recommend it. You can also ask the legal department at your university/institution for advice and whether they can provide backup.
If you have a website, you can disavow the article there, though that would also publicize it.
However, your name probably isn't unique. It is possible this was done by someone with the same name, though that seems unlikely. Explore the ORCID researcher ID system if you haven't already.

Thank you! My name isn't unique, but my name and the matching affiliation given in the article identify me uniquely and unambiguously.

It might be worth checking the legal department's position first, since if this is a persistent offender there might already be work under way to clip its wings.

Is your name really not unique, @DiomidisSpinellis? I mean, that's a very rare Greek name (I don't think I have ever met any Διομήδηδες in real life) combined with a non-Greek surname. I would be very surprised if there are more of you around.

I have once directly witnessed how a single email has achieved desired results immediately in a case quite similar to OP’s. Basically it threatened legal action.

I would say "Just ignore it or, even better, make fun of the whole story and spread it as wide as you can". Any person who knows you will then laugh with you, and anyone who does not will perceive your name on the article the same way he/she perceived it before it appeared there: as a meaningless combination of letters that will be entirely forgotten the very moment his/her eyes move away from the author line (that's exactly what happened with me when I looked at your linked reference). So it will be only the journal that would lose the reputation in anyone's eyes.
It is the same advice as it was given in the old dialogue:
A: How are you always so calm and in a good mood?
B: I never argue with idiots.
A: But that is not a method!
B: You are absolutely right, Sir!
Just my two cents. :-)

Tell the journal. If they're a serious journal, they'll take down the article (and improve their processes, since those evidently failed spectacularly). You can also try to reach an editorial board member.
If they're not a serious journal (their website does not inspire confidence; I can't find the editor-in-chief's profile at berkeley.edu), contacting a lawyer might be your only option.

The editor in chief appears to be "Cr Castro Valley, University of California, Berkeley, United States".  Castro Valley appears to be the area of San Fransisco to the South East of Berkeley, but still in the same County. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castro_Valley,_California

I do not think OP will want to burn money to fight shadows.

Seems like university lawyers might be able to draft a serious sounding letter, at a minimum… I don’t think it needs outside counsel.

Let's say the Journal takes down the publication -- well now the OP has a retraction, which is less than ideal.

The domain of the journal is not active right now, and the owner of the site seems to hide his identity.
Obviously, the entire site, mellbaou.com, is scam, and by asking this question you have just taken an important step to inform the world.
If you want to do more, then you can alert your local authorities, and if they have got time for your case, then the domain might be blocked in DNS-services.
The certificate for mellbaou.com is issued by Let's Encrypt, and their advice for cases like this one goes as follows:

A website using Let’s Encrypt is engaged in Phishing/Malware/Scam/… ,
what should I do? We recommend reporting such sites to Google Safe
Browsing and the Microsoft Smart Screen program, which are able to
more effectively protect users. Here are the reporting URLs:

https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_badware/
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/support/report-unsafe-site-guest



The link seems to work just fine.

It looks like the website took down the article in question. I tried searching for any articles by the author (based on his username here on StackExchange) and there were no results. So...this answer is irrelevant to the OP, and the last bit is meant tongue in cheek.
I echo what others have said about contacting the journal, explaining the situation, and having it taken down. If they were a serious journal (ha!), then their reputation would suffer if they kept it, so they'd be motivated to take it down. The last thing they want is negative publicity. I'm glad it worked for the OP
Defamation
You stand to gain or lose reputation if somebody publishes as you, and if it's AI, it could be damaging to you. You could threaten legal trouble. Start with mentioning your concern. If they don't fix it, step up and threaten legal issues. If they still don't budge (or respond), you could consider getting a lawyer and following through. (Many jurisdictions allow you to recover court/lawyer fees when suing, so this might not cost you anything — best to ask a lawyer for legal advice, though. Many have free consultations.)
Keep As a Joke
If the AI-generated work is as bad as it sounds, most serious scholars wouldn't see it and think it was really written by you. If you have a small field in which you all kinda know each other, you could announce it and laugh at it together. Bonus points for you if anyone actually cites it (as a example of AI, hopefully—it wouldn't be the first time a paper with a false author was cited!).
Royalties
If the journal makes money off the article that was submitted under your name, perhaps you'd be entitled to some sort of royalties for the (mis-)use of your likeness. One can hope, and one can dream. ;-)

I don't know how you are searching, but just putting OP's username into Google Scholar delivers a profile with 472 entries and close to 15k citations (I tried myself, since I know OP personally and was surprised that you "couldn't find articles by him" - there are many, and they are not hard to find in general). The offending paper is also listed by Google Scholar, easy to find if you sort by year.
